# fetch api call data is not defined

Tags: reactjs

Hey all I have a react app making a fetch api get request. When I console log the response after turning it into json it works fine but when I try to set state with data it says it is not defined. What am I missing?

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/logs')
      .then(res => res.json())
      // .then(data => console.log(data))
      .then(this.setState({ Log: data }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second chain expects a callback function, which `setState` is not.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/logs')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ Log: data })) // <---- wrap setState inside callback
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Comment: You are quite kind